# Export a multi-line variable to a file in azure-devops yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a key-vault secret called `mySecret`

mySecret:

```
foo="val1"
bar="val2"
baz="val3"
```

my pipeline shall create a file with `mySecret` values

```yaml
variables:  
- group: myKeyVault

steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tfvars]$(mySecret)"
      cat <<< "$(tfvars)" > terraform.tfvars
    displayName: export mySecret
```

Problem 1: `cat <<< "$(tfvars)" > terraform.tfvars` shall not echo out `$tfvars` in the pipeline log. Even `$mySecret` doesn't hold any secret content.

Problem 2: `terraform.tfvars` remain empty.

The overall idea is - you guessed it - to create `terraform.tfvars` file from a key-vault.

Comment: I'm fairly certain DevOps pipelines will not print key vault secret values by design. Does this work with a single-line secret?

Comment: I haven't tested it with a single line value. I tried successfully a work-around by writing the file from `azure cli` with `az keyvault secret show --name xxx --vault-name yyy  --query "value" -otsv > production.auto.tfvars`. Not the most beautiful solution but it works.

Comment: You should propose a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by reading the keyvault value over the cli:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: environment
    default: 'production'
  - name: keyvault
    default: 'myKeyVault'

steps:
  - bash: |
      az keyvault secret show \
        --name "${{ parameters.environment }}-tfvars" \
        --vault-name "${{ parameters.keyvault }}" \
        --query "value" -otsv > ${{ parameters.environment }}.auto.tfvars
    displayName: Set Variables
```